# How to get rank for each row with group by in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like below

```
Col_1   Col_2   Comment
1       ABC     test
1       ABC     test1
1       ABC     test2
2       DEF     xtest
2       DEF     xtest1
3       XYZ     ytest
3       XYZ     ytest1
3       XYZ     ytest2
```

And the result I want is

```
1       ABC     test | test1
2       DEF     xtest | xtest1
3       XYZ     ytest | ytest1
```

So I want to group by Col_1 and Col_2 and aggregate **only the first 2 values** of Comment column.

Any idea?

Comment: How do you define "first 2 values"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets so there is no such thing as a first value.

Comment: The the first table is arrived by a query where it is ordered by a certain column. The values are ordered already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 11g Release 2 supports the LISTAGG function.

```
SELECT col_1, 
       col_2, 
       Listagg(COMMENT, '|') 
         within GROUP (ORDER BY COMMENT) AS new_comment 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Row_number() 
                 over ( 
                   PARTITION BY col_1, col_2 
                   ORDER BY COMMENT) AS n 
        FROM   yourtable) 
WHERE  n <= 2 
GROUP  BY col_1, 
          col_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get two values using `min()` and `max()`:

```
select col_1, col_2, min(comment) || ' | ' || max(comment)
from t
group by col_1, col_2;
```

SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there is no such thing as "the first two comments".